# Slick not working on orientation change/window resize on iPhone / iPad Chrome

Tags: jquery, orientation, slick.js

Run into a strange issue with using `resize orientationchange` to resize my slack carousel on iPhone and iPad chrome only.

My aim is to have slick run whilst on mobile portrait, but depending on the screen width, on landscape it should go back to how it would look on desktop, which removes the slick carousel. I have attached some images below of what it looks like on an android device which is working fine, and also what it looks like on iPhone which doesn't seem to work.

[image]
[image]

My slick js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".carousel").slick( {
        slide:".slide",
        slidesToShow:2,
        slidesToScroll:1,
        autoplay:1,
        infinite: true,
        autoplaySpeed:2000,
        mobileFirst: true,
        responsive:[{
            breakpoint:500,
            settings: { slidesToShow: 3 }
        },{
            breakpoint: 650,
            settings: 'unslick'
        }]
    });
});
```

and for the resizer:

```
$(window).on("resize orientationchange", function() {
    $(".carousel").slick("resize");
});
```

This code works fine on all other devices and browsers and works fine on iPhone / iPad Safari. Any research I have done on this would lead me to suggest that `resize orientationchange` should have fixed this.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: Afraid not.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into similar issue (trying to show single slide on mobile portrait and 2 on mobile landscape mode) but only on iphone and ipad Safari. Chrome works fine for me.
I also followed this: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1933

but looks like no one else ran into such issues. hopefully we'll get solution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31485398)